# Call a method in a class when a property of an injected object changes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

If I have a member, constructor and method like so

```
//The injected object exposes a public property of type bool which will raise
//a NotifyPropertyChangedEvent
IInjectedObject _injectedObject;

public someClass(IInjectedObject injectedObject)
{
    _injectedObject = injectedObject;
}

public void DoSomething()
{

}
```

Is there a way to call the method in my class when the property on the injected object changes?

Comment: You should expose a `Change` event in the injected object, and fire it whenever the property changes. As far as I know, there is no way to have this done automatically.

Comment: This article from MSDN will help you out, it explains how to implement the [**Property Change Notification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: You can have the injectedObject raise an event and your someClass can subsribe to that. Another way is through implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that your interface inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged, so it can reasonably be expected to notify listeners of property changes through the "PropertyChanged" event.  Assuming something like this:

```
public interface IInjectedObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool MyImportantProperty { get; }
}
```

Then, your dependant object must listen for the [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event:

```
public class MyDependantClass
{
    public MyDependantClass(IInjectedObject injectedObject)
    {
        MyInjectedObject = injectedObject;
    }

    // We wrap the private field in a protected property,
    // to capture the event subscriptions
    private IInjectedObject _myInjectedObject;
    protected IInjectedObject MyInjectedObject
    {
        get { return _myInjectedObject; }
        set
        {
            // unsubscribe from the old property's event
            if(_myInjectedObject!= null)
                _myInjectedObject.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;

            _myInjectedObject= value;

            // subscribe to the new property's event
            if(_myInjectedObject!= null)
               _myInjectedObject.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "MyImportantProperty")
        {
            //react to the changed property here!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to attempt this answer and get back to you. The injected object implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the property I am interested in raises that event. How would that change your example above?

Comment: The example would remain pretty much identical, except you would subscribe to the "INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged" event.  The event handler would expect "PropertyChangedEventArgs" instead of "EventArgs."

Comment: I've edited the above answer in response to your updated question.

Comment: Refer to the example interface at the top of my answer; your object likely implements IInjectedObject and INotifyPropertyChanged separately.  You can either modify IInjectedObject to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged (thus including the "PropertyChanged" event in your IInjectedObject interface), or forefully cast the object to INotifyPropertyChanged in your property setter.  I don't recommend the second option, since you have no guarantee that you can always cast.